# Sending email messages using nodemailer

Tags: html, node.js, html-email

I am using nodemailer to send email messages from my server (Node.js) and currently, i'm using this generic function:

```
// Generic Inner Function - Send Email
exports.sendEmail = function(email, message, emailType){
    if((email)&&(message)&&(emailType)){
        var subject;
        if(emailType == "signUp")
            subject = "Welcome to my site - ";
        if(emailType == "forgotPass")
            subject = "Recovery Password from my site - ";
        if(emailType == "newResult")
            subject = "We have Found New Results for you - ";
        if(emailType == "arrivedPrice")
            subject = "Product Arrived - ";
        if(emailType == "tonePrice")
            subject = "Product Arrived tone - ️";

        console.log("Send Email to: "+email+" / Email Type: "+emailType);
        'use strict';
        const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

        // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'tester@gmail.com',
                pass: 'test'
            }
        });

        // setup email data with unicode symbols
        let mailOptions = {
            from: '"tom " <tester@gmail.com>', // sender address
            to: email, // list of receivers
            subject: subject, // Subject line
            text: message, // plain text body
            html: '<b>'+message+'</b>' // html body
        };

        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }
            console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
        });
    }
};
```

Now, I was creating a new HTML messages that I want to send according to the action the user is doing and I am struggling with how to do it.
I want to use Nodemailer to do this operation and I didn't find information over the web.

Sample of the HTML message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>A Simple Responsive HTML Email</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%!important;}
  img {height: auto;}
  .content {width: 100%; max-width: 600px;}
  .header {padding: 40px 30px 20px 30px;}
  .innerpadding {padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;}
  .borderbottom {border-bottom: 1px solid #f2eeed;}
  .subhead {font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; letter-spacing: 10px;}
  .h1, .h2, .bodycopy {color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;}
  .h1 {font-size: 33px; line-height: 38px; font-weight: bold;}
  .h2 {padding: 0 0 15px 0; font-size: 24px; line-height: 28px; font-weight: bold;}
  .bodycopy {font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px;}
  .button {text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 30px 0 30px;}
  .button a {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;}
  .footer {padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;}
  .footercopy {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;}
  .footercopy a {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;}

  @media only screen and (max-width: 550px), screen and (max-device-width: 550px) {
  body[yahoo] .hide {display: none!important;}
  body[yahoo] .buttonwrapper {background-color: transparent!important;}
  body[yahoo] .button {padding: 0px!important;}
  body[yahoo] .button a {background-color: #00ae9d; padding: 15px 15px 13px!important;}
  body[yahoo] .unsubscribe {display: block; margin-top: 20px; padding: 10px 50px; background: #2f3942; border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none!important; font-weight: bold;}
  }

  /*@media only screen and (min-device-width: 601px) {
    .content {width: 600px !important;}
    .col425 {width: 425px!important;}
    .col380 {width: 380px!important;}
    }*/

  </style>
</head>

<body yahoo bgcolor="#f6f8f1">
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#f6f8f1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
    <![endif]-->
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" class="content" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#c7d8a7" class="header">
          <table width="70" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td height="70" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
                <img class="fix" src="email/logoC.png" width="70" height="70" border="0" alt="" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="425" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td>
          <![endif]-->
          <table class="col425" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 425px;">
            <tr>
              <td height="70">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="subhead" style="padding: 0 0 0 3px;">
                      Tester
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="h1" style="padding: 5px 0 0 0;">
                      Chasing For You
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="innerpadding borderbottom">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td class="h2">
                Welcome to Cricket !
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="bodycopy">
              We're so happy you have joined our family!!!
              <br/>
              We founded Tester because we wanted to create a trustworthy app 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="innerpadding borderbottom">
          <table width="115" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td height="115" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
                <img class="fix" src="email/testimonial-bg.jpg" width="115" height="115" border="0" alt="" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="380" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td>
          <![endif]-->
          <table class="col380" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 380px;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="bodycopy">
                        Tester offers a Chrome extension that lets you set a.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" bgcolor="#00ae9d" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" height="45">
                            <a href="#">GET THE EXTENSION</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="innerpadding borderbottom">
          <table width="115" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td height="115" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
                <img class="fix" src="email/mobile.jpg" width="115" height="115" border="0" alt="" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="380" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td>
          <![endif]-->
          <table class="col380" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 380px;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="bodycopy">
                         Tester is also offers an Android App that lets you.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" bgcolor="#00ae9d" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" height="45">
                            <a href="#">GET THE APP</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="innerpadding borderbottom">
          <img class="fix" src="email/coffee3.jpg" width="100%" border="0" alt="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
<!--
      <tr>
        <td class="innerpadding bodycopy">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus adipiscing felis, sit amet blandit ipsum volutpat sed. Morbi porttitor, eget accumsan dictum, nisi libero ultricies ipsum, in posuere mauris neque at erat.
        </td>
      </tr>
-->
      <tr>
        <td class="footer" bgcolor="#44525f">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" class="footercopy">
                &reg; Copyright &copy; 2017 - Designed &amp; Developed by Cricket Team <br/>
                <a href="#" class="unsubscribe"><font color="#ffffff">Unsubscribe</font></a>
                <span class="hide">from Test newsletter</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="37" style="text-align: center; padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
                      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/">
                        <img src="email/facebook.png" width="37" height="37" alt="Facebook" border="0" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="37" style="text-align: center; padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
                      <a href="http://www.twitter.com/">
                        <img src="email/twitter.png" width="37" height="37" alt="Twitter" border="0" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you able to send anything?

Comment: Yes, these I can send:         if(emailType == "signUp")
            subject = "Welcome to my site - ";
        if(emailType == "forgotPass")
            subject = "Recovery Password from my site - ";
        if(emailType == "newResult")
            subject = "We have Found New Results for you - ";
        if(emailType == "arrivedPrice")
            subject = "Product Arrived - ";
        if(emailType == "tonePrice")
            subject = "Product Arrived tone - ️";

Comment: The messages are sent to email, but I want to change them to what I created.

Comment: Tried to put the contents of the email in the variable email and try to send?

Comment: No, I didn't. It is possible to create templates and call them from the server each time they called ?

Comment: Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: I will check it and tell you.

Comment: I was trying to do it but without success.